# Almacenar archivos en Datagridview para guardar en SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

Porfa, salvenme.
Estoy realizando un sistema de denuncias en VB.net y SQLServer 2014, lo que preciso es que a la hora de guardar registros, tengo que adjuntar imagenes que sirven como evidencias.[image: Este es el diseño que estoy manejando, centremonos en la parte azul de la derecha, la cual es un DataGridView de Bunifu]
Este es el diseño que estoy manejando, centremonos en la parte azul de la derecha, la cual es un DataGridView de Bunifu.

Lo que necesito saber es como almacenar temporalmente todo tipo de archivos(imagenes, videos, documentos, pdf, etc...) en el datagridview en forma de byte para que posteriormente cuando haga click en el boton guardar, se guarden en la tabla de la base.
La tabla de los datos y de las evidencias no son las mismas, son separadas, la tabla de los datos se llama "personas" y la de las evidencias "evidenciaspersonas"
El actual codigo del boton guardar es el siguiente:

```
    Private Sub btnguardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnguardar.Click
    If TabControl2.SelectedTab Is TabPage3 Then
        sentencia = "INSERT INTO personas(nombre, identidad, institucion, ubicacion, puesto, hechos, tipodeabuso, nombred, direcciond, telefono, correo, estado) Values('" + txtnombre.Text + "','" + txtid.Text + "','" + txtinstituto.Text + "','" + txtubicacion.Text + "','" + txtnivel.Text + "','" + txthechos.Text + "','" + cmbtipo.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "')"
        mensaje = "Datos insertados correctamente"
        ejecutarsql(sentencia, mensaje)
        mostrarpersonas()
    End If
End Sub
```

Claro que para adjuntar los archivos, tengo que colocar un botón con un OpenFileDialog, el datagridview no tiene filas hasta el momento porque pues no se sabe cuantos archivos se van a subir por cada registro, asi que de ser posible, a la hora de seleccionar los archivos, ya sean uno o varios, se creen las filas en función de cuantos archivos se seleccionaron, una vez estén alojados en el datagrid, al dar click en el boton guardar, se guardarán en la base de datos, vaciando el datagrid y mostrando el contenido de la tabla de evidencias, en el datagrid se alojarán los archivos únicamente cuando se ingresará un nuevo registro.

[image: Los campos de las evidencias siguen de este modo hasta llegar a doc85]
los campos de las evidencias siguen de este modo hasta llegar a doc85.

Si me hace falta brindar más información, la daré conforme se requiera, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Estimado, favor tener en cuenta que almacenar las imagenes en forma de bits solo llenará y hará tu base de datos demasiado pesada, lo digo como experiencia. Te recomiendo almacenar las imagenes en carpetas dentro de tu server y encriptar la dirección URL para poder encontrarla.

Comment: Hola que tal, muchas gracias por el aporte, pero la verdad, no tengo ni la minima idea de como hacer eso, si pudiera guiarme un poco, le agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para convertir los archivos a bytes, podés usar:

```
Dim mBytes As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(RutaArchivo)
MiDataGridView.Rows.Add(mBytes)
```

O podés almacernar la ruta del archivo en el DataGridView y convertirlo a Byte() al momento de guardar el registro.